# How to use vuex in router

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to read data from `store` in `router`，but it doesn't work

I try three methods but no one is right

tried to use

```
// ReferenceError: store is not defined
console.log(store.state); 

// ReferenceError: $store is not defined
console.log($store.state);

// TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined
console.log(this.$store.state);
```

If I use it in `App.vue` it can work.

App.vue

```
export default {
  created() {
    console.log(this.$store.state.user);
  },
}
```

What should I do?

---

store/index.js

```
state: {
  user: {
    loggedIn: false,
    data: null
  },
},
```

router/inde.js

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
    // console.log(store.state);
    // console.log($store.state);
    console.log(this.$store.state);
   // if(this.$store.state.user.loggedIn){
   // next('/login');
  }else
    next();
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing it:

```
import store from '../store/';
```

And then use it as follows:

```
store.state
```

Make sure you're exporting it in `store/index.js`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
     //config
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can use `$store` in **App.vue** is that you imported **store.js** in your **app.js** and added to Vue instance.
if you want to use your vuex store in another js file you just need to import it.

```
import Store from './store.js';

console.log(Store);
```

Comment: I would've upvoted this answer if Store was lowercase; typically non-constructor code is lower case.